# Merging row data based on a column value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I need to combine them based on same values of C column

[Create a copy here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/114Yjr79TpVYJvXODKygHxzLRESJlXKpqRQVfn5qRkgM/copy)
[Open the sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/114Yjr79TpVYJvXODKygHxzLRESJlXKpqRQVfn5qRkgM/edit#gid=0)
I have tried with '=QUERY(A2:I7,"select A,B,Max(C),D,E,F,G,H,I where A is not null group by C,B,A,D,E,F,G,H,I")

But that doesnt work.
The expected results are shown in the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=QUERY(A2:I7, "select A, B, C, max(D), max(E), max(F), G, max(H), I group by A, B, C, G, I")
```